# Excel dynamic search vba code

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

With this VBA macro for Excel I get instant search filter when I type the whole word, but I want it as follows: when I type <kbd>O</kbd> for opel, that I get opel already showing.

This is the code:

```
Sub MG26Nov26
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim Ray As Variant
If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Else
        If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If
    Ray = Split(TextBox1, "+")
    Sheet1.Range("A2:F" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=Ray, Operator:=xlFilterValues  
    End If

End Sub
```

This is the test file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KDwE2jT_u35wPhd5dR7Xi3X31ddzXDNx

Comment: Try changing ray to `Ray = Split(TextBox1 & "*", "+")`

Comment: This worked for me too. You have really excel skills! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To solve the issue, you can use the below written VBA code.**

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
Dim Ray As Variant
If Len(TextBox1.Value) = 0 Then
    Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
    Else
        If Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = True Then
            Sheet1.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If

    Sheet1.Range("A2:F" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Text & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If

End Sub
```

**N.B.** This is the Change I've done in the VBA Code `Criteria1:="*" & TextBox1.Text & "*"` in place of the `Ray` variable.

Comment: Woowww that worked for me.Thank your very much!!

Comment: @LouaiAlFalahi,, glad to help you and happy to learn that my solution worked for you. If you wish accept it as Answer also you can up vote it ☺